# How to prevent Mistral-7B-instruct on Vertex AI endpoint from truncating responses

Tags: json, rest, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm using [the prompt template directly from Mistral](https://docs.mistral.ai/models/):

```
{
  "instances": [
    {
      "prompt": "<s>[INST] What is your favourite colour and why? [/INST]My favorite color is blue.</s>[INST] And which one after that? [/INST]"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": {
    "max_tokens": -1
  }
}
```

It includes multiple [INST]-blocks because it's for a chat-style interaction that reuses the previous requests and responses as context.

Then use this command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://europe-west4-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/europe-west4/endpoints/${ENDPOINT_ID}:predict -d "@request.json"
```

And this is a typical response:

```
{
  "predictions": [
    "Prompt:\n\u003cs\u003e[INST] What is your favourite colour and why? [/INST]My favorite color is blue.\u003c/s\u003e[INST] And which one after that? [/INST]\nOutput:\n My second favorite color is green. This is because it is a color that represents"
  ],
  "deployedModelId": "[REDACTED]",
  "model": "projects/[REDACTED]/locations/europe-west4/models/mistral-7b-instruct-v0_1",
  "modelDisplayName": "mistral-7b-instruct-v0_1",
  "modelVersionId": "1"
}
```

As you can see the response is short, which is fine, but it's also truncated somehow. What causes this?

I have tried the following:

- Different values for max_tokens such as -1, 500, 2048 and not including max_tokens at all.
- Escaping the prompt in different ways, including escaping the forward slashes.

Am I still doing something wrong? Or does the Vertex AI endpoint mangle my JSON somehow?

Comment: Hi @Deckard,  It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/?hl=en). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.